# Need plug in to convert freestyle jobs in to pipeline (declarative)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I need to convert the jenkins freestyle jobs in to pipeline (declarative).  Can some one let me know if there are any plugins available to do this.
i am using opensource jenkins version 2.19.4

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest [upgrade; latest](https://www.jenkins.io/download/) is 2.235.1, but go at least 2.222.4. 2.19.4 is way too old an LTS veraion. That was the 2nd 2.x LTS. You need better pipeline support, better plugins and security fixes and generally more refined.

Next, did you read [Jenkins blog](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/12/15/auto-convert-freestyle-jenkins-jobs-to-coded-pipeline/) ?

Or [Cloubees blog](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/pipelines-user-guide/declarative-pipeline-migration-assistant) ?